# SQL Query with RollUp

Tags: sql, sql-server

this is my query

```
select X.Memo, X.Month, Format(sum(X.[Total Sales S$]),'#,0.00') as [Rental Sales $]
    , Format(sum(X.[Net GP S$]),'#,0.00') as [Rental GP $]
from Data X
group by X.Month,X.Memo
```

This is my result:

[image]

Expected result should be like this:

[image]

is it possible to do it in SQL? Can help me in the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use case statement and get the result you mentioned. 
you can add requird columns in the similar way and get the output.

```sql
SELECT MONTH,
  sum(CASE WHEN Memo = 'Rental' THEN sales$ END) Rental_$,
  sum(CASE WHEN Memo = 'Rental' THEN GP$ END) Rental_GP,
  sum(CASE WHEN Memo = 'Sales' THEN sales$ END) Sales_$,
  sum(CASE WHEN Memo = 'Sales' THEN GP$ END) Sales_GP
FROM tablea
GROUP BY MONTH
```

```sql
SELECT MONTH,
  Format(sum(CASE WHEN Memo = 'Rental' THEN (X.[Total Sales S$]) END), '#,0.00') Rental_$,
  Format(sum(CASE WHEN Memo = 'Rental' THEN (X.[Net GP S$]) END), '#,0.00') Rental_GP,
  Format(sum(CASE WHEN Memo = 'Sales' THEN (X.[Total Sales S$]) END), '#,0.00') Sales_$,
  Format(sum(CASE WHEN Memo = 'Sales' THEN (X.[Net GP S$]) END), '#,0.00') Sales_GP,
  Format((sum(CASE WHEN Memo = 'Rental' THEN (X.[Total Sales S$]) END) + sum(CASE WHEN Memo = 'Sales' THEN (X.[Total Sales S$]) END)), '#,0.00') [Total Sales S$],
  Format((sum(CASE WHEN Memo = 'Rental' THEN (X.[Net GP S$]) END) + sum(CASE WHEN Memo = 'Sales' THEN (X.[Net GP S$]) END)), '#,0.00') [Total GP S$]
FROM DATA X
GROUP BY MONTH WITH ROLLUP
ORDER BY SUM(X.MN) ASC
```